# Solution for Javascript toFixed and math.round wrong issue

Tags: javascript, tofixed

Is there a way to proper round the number 35.855 to have two decimals in javascript? Trying to round it has different solutions based on the environment (35.85 in Chrome, 35.86 in IE9).

I was looking for a solution at which javascript does wrong rounding for the decimals (rounding .5 values down instead up) and haven't found a solution that covered all the values that I had. They behaved other in different environments / browsers.

```js
console.log(Math.round(35.855*100)/100);
// result: 35.85 (IE9 : 35.86, Chrome: 35.85 ???)
console.log((35.855).toFixed(2));
// result: 35.85
```

Comment: JavaScript does not round values incorrectly. *e* IE9 is over 12 years old and pretty much not relevant. Modern IE ("Edge") is based on Chromium.

Comment: @Pointy But IE9 has expected behavior and Chrome has unexpected behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Okay just create a node.js project or use the chrome devtool and type both the `console.log(...)` commands in it. You're pointing out something there. IE9 is old and pretty much not relevant, but it does right rounding. Would agree with your point, if it would be the opposite?

Comment: `35.855*100` is `3585.4999999999995` and `Math.round(3585.4999999999995` is `3585`: https://jsfiddle.net/c1nfqse5/. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @jabaa yeah at least it explains why it comes to this behavior, but doesn't solve it. I still have the wrong rounded numbers, to which I have to think of an solution of to make proper calculations. Don't want to get sued because of a wrong calculation by an half cent in a price. :D

Comment: Never use floating point math for currencies. Use integer math and use the smallest coin value as base.

Comment: Could you elaborate the point with the integer math.

Comment: Assuming I want to work with Euros. I would use `const price = 1234;` for 12.34€. The whole math is integer math without floating point errors. `0.1 + 0.2` is not `0.3`. You could be sued even without rounding. But `10 + 20` is `30`.

Comment: @jabaa I know it is a question & answer platform, should I just rephrase my post now to have a question in it, instead just get directly to the point? :D

Comment: Yes, ask a question, otherwise I would downvote and vote to close and I would also downvote the answer, because it's unclear what question it answers.

Comment: So you want me to redesign the whole customer database and their whole numeric calculations in their backend, to work with integers instead of floats? That sounds a bit ridiculous, doesn't it? Why would I get sued even without rounding? I'm not sure, if I understand your point properly.

Comment: If you're actually using floating point math for money, yes, I strongly recommend to redesign it. That's really horrible and could become very expensive. You could get sued, because even $0.1 + $0.2 returns a wrong value. Try `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3`

Comment: @SercanSametSavran every financial website I have worked on over the past 20+ years has used something like Java "BigDecimal" (fixed-point math), and systems like that have been the standard dating back to the 1960s with IBM mainframe BCD math hardware. You cannot, cannot use binary floating point for "money math". It's simply a rule of life.

Comment: Your question is _"Is there a way to proper round the number 35.855 in javascript?"_ The proper way is `Math.roung(35.855)` and the result is `36`. The posted answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Okay. I think today was a good day to learn something new. I have never worked for a financial website and the environment I'm speaking about is just an online shop. The only thing that needs to be calculated here is a percental discount. So not a financial institute or a bitcoin exchange website, where the precision is very important. So I think they will do fine without the redesign to integer math.

Comment: @jabaa For gods sake. I already edited the post to have a question in it. Why don't we just focus on the main thought to help other people, instead of doing this right here? What is the point? I mean people struggling with the exact same issue, will understand the question and will probably grateful for the post with the answer. What exactly are you trying to do here? Also you haven't gave me event the chance, to edit it to a question and already voted the post for question. Why are you behaving so offended actually?

Comment: A question and answer platform doesn't work if the questions don't contain questions or the answers don't answer the questions. How could other user verify the posted answer if it's unclear what question they answer? How could other users post better answers if it's unclear?

Comment: "So you want me to redesign the whole customer database and their whole numeric calculations in their backend, to work with integers instead of floats?" Yes. Using floats to represent currency would be considered a major design flaw.

Comment: @chiliNUT The values are saved with the decimal type of mysql on the database, which is good actually for currencies. Everything else is calculated on their behalf with database functions. The only calculation that is done with floating numbers in their „backend“ is to generate frontend data and not for calculations of the real value. So to just give the user a preview and rounding issues and that they can occur on the views are already regulated in their eula. You are all right if I would do the calculations for real values, but it‘s just to precalculate and display data on frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make rounding of 1 character after the decimal part:

```js
const round = (num, digits = 2) => {
  const str = num.toString(), idx = str.indexOf('.');
  if (idx < 0) return num;
  const left = str[idx + 1 + digits]; // round this char
  if (!left) return num;
  return parseFloat(str.slice(0, idx + 1 + digits)) + 
      (left >= 5) * (str[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1) / 10 ** digits;
}
[35.855, 35.8549999, [-35.8549999, 3], 35.895, 35.8, 35].forEach(num => 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(num), '->', round(...[].concat(num))));
```

And a benchmark:

```
Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/117
------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander slice       151/min  1.0x  163  166  159  151  169
Sercan Samet Savran   845/min  5.6x  846  845  846  851  859
------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000">

// @benchmark Alexander slice
const round = (num, digits = 2) => {
  const str = num.toString();
  const idx = str.indexOf('.');
  if(idx < 0){
    return num;
  }
  const left = str[idx + 1 + digits];
  return left ? parseFloat(str.slice(0, idx + 1 + digits)) +(left >= 5) * (str[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1)/ 10 ** digits : num;
}
// @run

round(35.855);
round(35.8549999);
round(35.8549999, 3);
round(35.85);
round(35.8);
round(35);

// @benchmark Sercan Samet Savran

function roundToTwoDecimal(myNumber){
    let myStrNumber = myNumber.toString();
    // checking our number has decimals and if enough decimal points are present 
    if(myStrNumber.split(".").length > 1 && myStrNumber.split(".")[1].length > 2){
        // doubling the last decimal e.g. 35.855 is now = 35.8555 and parsing back to float  
        myStrNumber += myStrNumber.substring(myStrNumber.length-1);
        myNumber = parseFloat(myStrNumber);
    } // no additional decimal needed here.
    // returning the myNumber*100 = 3585.55 ---round--> 3586 / 100 = 35.86 
    return Math.round(myNumber*100)/100;
}

// @run

roundToTwoDecimal(35.855);
roundToTwoDecimal(35.8549999);
roundToTwoDecimal(35.8549999, 3);
roundToTwoDecimal(35.85);
roundToTwoDecimal(35.8);
roundToTwoDecimal(35);


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice one. Do you think, working with regex will be more performant in that case?

Comment: @SercanSametSavran i want to split manually and make a benchmark

Comment: Thank you. That would be great. Looking forward for the results.

Comment: @SercanSametSavran finished, removed the regex version since it's twice slower

Comment: @SercanSametSavran if it solves your problem don't hesitate to accept it (the checkbox), thanks

Comment: Sorry for late response. This works without any issues so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is just to add the same digit at the end of the number (if there are more than 1 digit), in order to force the previous number to round properly.

```js
function roundToTwoDecimal(myNumber){
    let myStrNumber = myNumber.toString();
    // checking our number has decimals and if enough decimal points are present 
    if(myStrNumber.split(".").length > 1 && myStrNumber.split(".")[1].length > 2){
        // doubling the last decimal e.g. 35.855 is now = 35.8555 and parsing back to float  
        myStrNumber += myStrNumber.substring(myStrNumber.length-1);
        myNumber = parseFloat(myStrNumber);
    } // no additional decimal needed here.
    // returning the myNumber*100 = 3585.55 ---round--> 3586 / 100 = 35.86 
    return Math.round(myNumber*100)/100;
}
```